# Reading and Printing a Matrix C

Tags: c, matrix

I have an assignment to read numbers from a file to form a matrix. 
The first two integers of each line are the row and column, and then the remaining integers are the data in the matrix.

```
2 2 1 2 3 4
```

looks like

```
1 2
3 4
```

I am able to successfully load in one matrix using:

```
void RdMatrix(FILE *file, int (*matrix)[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int *row, int *column)
{
    int data;

    int matRow = RdRowSize(file);
    int matCol = RdColumnSize(file);
    *row = matRow;
    *column = matCol;
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < matRow; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < matCol; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &data);
            *matrix[i][j] = data;
        }
}
```

Then I can print it with

```
void PrMat(int(*matrix)[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int row, int col)
{   
    int i, j;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

In my main function, I have two matrices `A[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE]` and `B[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE]`, a `rowA = 0, colA = 0;` and `rowB = 0, colB = 0;`.
I call `RdMatrix(fpin, &A, &rowA, &columnA);  RdMatrix(fpin, &B, &rowB, &columnB); PrMat(&A, rowA, columnA);`

The input looks like:

```
2 2 1 2 3 4
2 2 9 8 7 6
```

Then it prints

```
1 2 
9 8

9 8 
7 6
```

When it should be printing

```
1 2
3 4

9 8
7 6
```

I'm not allowed to use any libraries, nor will it help, since I have to re-write this in assembly later.

EDIT: Including Code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXSIZE 10
FILE *fpin;

int RdRowSize(FILE *file)
{   
    int row;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &row);
    return row;
}

int RdColumnSize(FILE *file)
{
    int col;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &col);
    return col;
}

void RdMatrix(FILE *file, int (*matrix)[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int *row, int *column)
{
    int data;

    int matRow = RdRowSize(file);
    int matCol = RdColumnSize(file);
    *row = matRow;
    *column = matCol;
    int i, j;

    printf("\n=====================\nLoading Matrix\n=====================\n");
    for (i = 0; i < matRow; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < matCol; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &data);
            *matrix[i][j] = data;
        }
    }
}

void PrMat(int(*matrix)[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], int row, int col)
{   
    int i, j;
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < row; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < col; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", *matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main(void) 
{

    int RsizeM, CsizeM;                                 /*matrix row size and column size*/
    int A[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE], B[MAXSIZE][MAXSIZE];       /*the two matrices*/
    int rowA=0, columnA=0, rowB=0, columnB=0;           /* the row and column sizes of A and B */




    /*open input file - file name is hardcoded*/
    fpin = fopen("INA1.txt", "r");                      /* open the file for reading */
    if (fpin == NULL) 
    {
        fprintf(stdout, "Cannot open input file  - Bye\n");
        return(-1);                                 /* if problem, exit program*/
    }
    /*ASSUMPTIONS: the file is not empty and contains has at least 1 set of matrices*/


    /* Add while loop after testing a single iteration */ 


    RdMatrix(fpin, &A, &rowA, &columnA);
    RdMatrix(fpin, &B, &rowB, &columnB);

    PrMat(&A, rowA, columnA);
    PrMat(&B, rowA, columnB);



    fclose(fpin);  /* close the file */

    return (0);
}
```

Then the file it has to open is called INA1.txt

Comment: Can you show the full code (including the main function)?

Comment: Posting compilable code helps us help you ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When referencing an element, you should use `(*matrix)[i][j]` instead of `*matrix[i][j]`.
Also, when printing the B matrix, it should be `rowB`, not `rowA`.

Comment: I believe you are right, but the real problem here was simply a mistype... ;)

Comment: The parenthesis around the *matrix fixed it. The rowA/rowB would have bitten me later. Thank you!